# Correcting an off-by-one bug encountered using take_while()?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17

A sequence of two integers, one decrementing each time and the other every third time until they both meet their limits (149 to 145 & 153 to 150).

```
(149, 153)
(148, 153)
(147, 153)
(146, 152)
(145, 152)
(145, 152)
(145, 151)
(145, 151)
(145, 151)
(145, 150)
```

There is an off-by-one bug in this implementation, it produces all but the last entry.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../Streams-master/source/Stream.h"
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
using namespace stream;
using namespace stream::op;
int main(){
    MakeStream::counter(149,-1) | map_([](auto x){return (x >= 145)?x:145;})
        | zip_with(MakeStream::counter(153,-1) | map_([](auto x){return (x >= 150)?x:150;})
            | flat_map([](auto x){return MakeStream::repeat(x,3);}) )
        | take_while([](auto t){return std::get<0>(t) != 145 || std::get<1>(t) != 150;})
        | for_each([](auto tup){std::cout << tup << std::endl;});
    }
```

Results:

```
(149, 153)
(148, 153)
(147, 153)
(146, 152)
(145, 152)
(145, 152)
(145, 151)
(145, 151)
(145, 151)
```

How do I get the last entry?

If this, want-the-one-that-tells-us-we-are-done, is a well known issue how is it handled in functional programming and C++ specifically?

Using [C++1z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) & [C++ Streams](http://jscheiny.github.io/Streams/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You want to stop at the first `(…, 145, 150)` *inclusively*. Unfortunately `take_while` is a bad fit for this purpose as the resulting stream stops just short of the first offending element, i.e. it works exclusively (for lack of a better term). This is more obvious with a simplified stream:

```
// pseudo-code
auto stream = { 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, /* only zeroes after that */ };
auto pred = …;
auto x = stream | take_while(pred);
// our goal
assert( x == { 1, 2, 3, 0 } );
```

What should be apparent here is that `take_while` will use `pred` on the first `0` it encounters, at which point we want it to return `true` since we want to keep it. But then we want it to return `false` on the next element, which is *also* `0`.

The three immediate options I can foresee are, in a vague order of personal preference:

- find or write a variant of `take_while` which includes the first value that doesn’t satisfy the predicate
- rewrite the initial stream so that it can be made to work with a different predicate
- write a tricky and stateful not-quite-predicate

This last approach can be considered somewhat problematic as it assumes that the library is okay with passing in a function object that is not (strictly speaking) a predicate, since it will return different values for the same argument. In our case the documentation doesn’t say a lot, so I leave it to your judgement. If you are okay with the approach, you can try something similar to:

```
auto lawful_predicate = [](auto const& t)
{ return std::get<1>(t) != 145 || std::get<2>(t) != 150; };

auto questionable_thing = [bool not_done = true, lawful_predicate](auto const& t) mutable
{ return std::exchange(not_done, lawful_predicate(t)); }
```

Note how our cheating is apparent since we have to mark `decltype(questionable_thing)::operator()` with `mutable`. If the library requires predicates to fulfil a e.g. `bool(Arg const&) const;` signature, it won’t be accepted. In which case you can be even more underhanded (but beware lifetime issues, make sure you understand what is going on here):

```
// we are now leaving inner bits around
bool innards = true;
auto the_worst_thing_ever = [&innards, lawful_predicate](auto const& t)
{ return std::exchange(innards, lawful_predicate(t)); }
```